# AJAX function on body change but generated html object on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In the following code, I have it currently set up that this function will trigger when the body of the webpage changes. Then it will look for `widget-pb-0-box_id`. If that exists, as it doesn't exist on load. Now the function will keep checking to see if the `widget` is changed then, will send the AJAX call. I would like to set this function so that the function will get triggered when `body` changes. And then `widget...` gets triggered on `keyup`. I tried by having nested functions however it cascades the calls and end up calling the function n+1 times every `keyup` in `widget...`.

```
$('body').on('change', '#widget-pb-0-box_id', function (e) {
    var data = {
        //data to be sent
    };

    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
        //AJAX call
    });
});
```

Comment: @Liam tried to clarify it.

Comment: *I have it currently set up that this function will trigger when the body of the webpage changes.* No you haven't you've attached an event watcher to the body that will trigger when the `#widget-pb-0-box_id` changes. So you want to watch for keyup? Keyup of what?

Comment: have you tried `.on('keyup', '#widget-pb-0-box_id'`. It depends what `#widget-pb-0-box_id` is. Show your HTML would be helpful

Comment: @Liam Yea that works. I guess i just needed a soundboard. Been hitting my head against this for a while. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the keyup event for an element, that does not exist at page load. Why do you use 'change' on 'body' for this? Figure out the point where this element gets created an append the 'keyup' event after that.

Or use the delegate event handler method described in the documentation (https://api.jquery.com/on/ see *Direct and delegated events*). Just use the keyup event directly

```
$('body').on('keyup', '#widget-pb-0-box_id', function (e) {
    var data = {
        //data to be sent
    };

    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
        //AJAX call
    });
});
```

Comment: *Figure out the point where this element gets created an append the 'keyup' event after that.* `.on` exists so that you don't have to do this. That's the point of it